# How to stop floating Divs wrapping (thumbnail)

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have a site - you can see it here i have a screenshot here i want to stop my readmore text wrapping around the image when its a small image and a large amount of text

```
<div class="page-list-ext-item">

<div class="page-list-ext-image"><img width="110" height="73" class="attachment-110x110 wp-post-image" src="#"></a></div>


<h3 class="page-list-ext-title">Heading</h3><div class="page-list-ext-item-content">TEXT

<br><br>read more on: <a href="#">Title</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add

```
.page-list-ext-item-content{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This will work.

Comment: This seemed to work straight up, So the hidden attribute only really custs content off if there is a height defined?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to rewrite your markup so that it can validate. The above markup won't validate. Browsers always try to fix invalid markup, but from a pure CSS perspective this kind off markup is often the main cause of several bugs. In your case, a float always need a container with a clearance on it, such as:

```
.clear:after {
    content: '.';
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This will clear the container of your thumbnail but you still need to fix your markup.

Comment: Hi i didnt need to do that i was able to add code as above, thanks for the help though